# How to properly set up php script in systemd service?

Tags: php, linux, systemd

SO,
I'm trying to set up a service using systemd on an Axis camera (I believe it's Arch linux or a very stripped down Linux version that's custom). I have the service set up as follows:

myservice.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ping Monitoring Daemon
After=network.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/listen-start.sh
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/listen-stop.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is listen-start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(curl http://website.com/logssomethingtoadatabase.php?action=start)
```

My php script:

```
<?php
echo 'Service Started';

while (true) {
$foo = print_r($_SERVER, true);

$blnStop = false;

if ( $_GET['action'] === 'start') {
    mail("test@myemail.com","Debug", "Camera service started with current values:\r\n\r\n" . $foo);
} else {
    mail("test@myemail.com","Debug", "Camera service stopped with current values:\r\n\r\n" . $foo);

    $blnStop = true;
}

if ( $blnStop ) {
    break 2;
}

sleep(60);
}

echo 'Service Stopped';
die();
?>
```

Issue I'm encountering is once I start the service, I'm unable to "stop it", even after issuing the "systemctl stop" and "disable" commands on it. I have to power cycle the camera to get it to stop emailing me. I can't seem to get it to "break" out of the while loop.

The goal here is to call that script every 60 seconds which is a device monitoring effort. I must use systemd in this case as that's all that the camera supports.

Additional info: The systemctl start and stop commands work successfully, and the script itself runs fine.

Can anyone see anything I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

the listen-stop.sh script is probably calling the php script with action=stop, right? probably like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(curl http://website.com/logssomethingtoadatabase.php?action=stop)
```

what you are trying to achieve in that `while (true)` loop will not work, because the php script that got triggered by the `start` call, will always have $_GET['action'] = 'start'. your subsequent execution of the `systemctl stop` will not affect that already running php script, this is why it never ends executing.

**QUESTION**: is that php script supposed to do anything in regards to the camera? or just send the mail notification that service started/stopped?

if its only the mail notification, then all you need to have in that php script is:

```
<?php

if ( $_GET['action'] === 'start') {
    mail("test@myemail.com","Debug", "Camera service started with current values:\r\n\r\n" . $foo);
    echo 'Service Started';
} else {
    mail("test@myemail.com","Debug", "Camera service stopped with current values:\r\n\r\n" . $foo);
    echo 'Service Stopped';
}

?>
```

**TL;DR**: you have written the script in a similar mode like a bash daemon script, but thats not how it works. on each execution of the php script, a new instance is created, so you cant "talk" to the instance you created when you executed the `systemctl start`.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Yes - the "stop" action changes URL as you described. The start script will ultimately log something to a database once I get this working. Is the "while(true)" method correct, or what's the best way to set this up to call that script every 10 minutes or so? Is the proper systemd entry supposed to be Type-oneshot or Type=simple?

Comment: the while(true) is correctly written but it doesnt offer you anything, it just makes the script stay in limbo (when you trigger it with action=start). you need some way externally to the php to trigger a new execution every 10 mins. you should check `crontab` in linux systems. Finally, i am not so familiar with the systemd-related question you are asking.